# Optimal time for Meal on Purim

Tags: purim, halacha, zemanim, meal-seudah

What is the optimal time for the Purim Seduah (Meal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Matzav.com:

It is good to study some Torah before beginning the Seudah, as the Posuk says “Layehudim Haysa Ohra V’Simcha…” and Chazal say Ohra is referring tothe light of Torah which should precede the Simcha! (Ram”a 695:2)**It is customary to daven Mincha before beginning the Seudah, as not to end up davening Mincha while drunk. The Seudah should begin when it is still daylight, and not close to sunset, so that most of the meal should be eaten during the day.**